# Linearization of constraint in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I have the following decision variables:

- $x$, which is binary, and
- $a, b, c > 0$, which are continuous.

I would like to express in linear form for a linear programming model the following constraints:

(a) if $x=1$, then $b < a$ AND $a \leq c$ (i.e. $b < a \leq c$),

(b) else if $x=0$, then $a \leq b$ XOR $c < a$.

Note: It always holds that $b < c$ (I do not know if this can simplify things).

I came up with the following linear constraints, using the big-M method and a small tolerance constant $\epsilon$:

(1) $b + \epsilon \leq a + M(1-x)$

(2) $a \leq c + M(1-x)$

(3) $a \leq b +Mx$

(4) $c + \epsilon \leq a +Mx$

However, (3) and (4) do not correctly convey the meaning of constraint in (b), since when $x=0$, then $a \leq b$ and $c < a$, which is impossible. Is there an elegant way to correct this, preferably without introducing another binary variable? Maybe the fact that $b < c$ could help in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (1) and (2) are correct.  To enforce
$$x=0 \implies (\text{$a \le b$ XOR $c < a$}),$$
first rewrite as
$$x=1 \lor (a \le b \land c \ge a) \lor (a > b \land c < a),$$
and then introduce binary variables $y$ and $z$, together with linear constraints
\begin{align}
x + y + z &\ge 1 \tag5\label5 \\
a-b &\le M(1-y) \tag6\label6 \\
a-c &\le M(1-y) \tag7\label7 \\
b-a+\epsilon &\le M(1-z) \tag8\label8 \\
c-a+\epsilon &\le M(1-z) \tag9\label9
\end{align}
If you also know that $b<c$, you can omit \eqref{7} and \eqref{8}, which are then dominated by \eqref{6} and \eqref{9}, respectively.

You cannot avoid introducing at least one binary variable because the feasible region for $x=0$ is not convex.  For example, $(a,b,c)=(0,1,2)$ and $(a,b,c)=(3,1,2)$ are both feasible, but their average is not.

---

By request, here is an alternative formulation with only one additional binary variable $y$. The idea is to enforce
$$(x=0 \land y=1) \implies a \le b$$
and
$$(x=0 \land y=0) \implies c < a,$$
which you can do with linear
constraints
\begin{align}
a-b &\le M(x+1-y)\tag{6’}\label{6p} \\
c-a+\epsilon &\le M(x+y) \tag{9’}\label{9p}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, as you mention, (7) and (8) can be omitted in the case of the particular problem. In that case, is it possible to reformulate the rest of the constraints in (5), (6) and (9) so that only one additional binary variable must be used?

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer!